# An Estimate for Newtonian Potential

Tags: real-analysis, potential-theory

Consider the Newtonian Potential $$u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{1}{|x-y|} f(y)dy$$, where $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the 3-dimensional Euclidian space. Show that if $|f(y)| \le C{|y|}^{-\alpha}$ for $2<\alpha<3$, then $|u(x)| \le C{|x|}^{2-\alpha}$ for $|x|>1$.

---

I am puzzled by this estimate. Clearly as long as $x$ is not $0$, the integral near $x$ will diverge to infinity. But the controlling condition for $f(y)$ looks so weak as to make the total estimate for $u(x)$ to hold. 
Thank you for help!

Comment: The condition is most certainly $|f(y)|\le C |y|^{-\alpha}$.

Comment: Oh I am extremely sorry for mistyping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write $x = \left|x\right| {\omega}$ with ${\omega} \in  {S}^{2}$ and
use the change of variable $y = \left|x\right| z$. One has

$$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}  \begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle  \int_{{\mathbb{R}}^{3}}^{}\frac{{\left|y\right|}^{{-{\alpha}}}}{\left|x-y\right|} d y&=&\displaystyle  \int_{{\mathbb{R}}^{3}}^{}\frac{{\left|x\right|}^{{-{\alpha}}} {\left|z\right|}^{{-{\alpha}}}}{\left|x-\left|x\right| z\right|} {\left|x\right|}^{3} d z\\
&=&{\left|x\right|}^{2-{\alpha}} \displaystyle  \int_{{\mathbb{R}}^{3}}^{}\frac{{\left|z\right|}^{{-{\alpha}}}}{\left|{\omega}-z\right|} d z\\
&=&K_\alpha {\left|x\right|}^{2-{\alpha}}
\end{array}$$

Comment: I understand your idea but does $K_{\alpha}$ converge to a constant?

Comment: $K_\alpha$ is a constant, I mean it only depends on $\alpha\in (2, 3)$. The integral converges near $|z|= +\infty$ because the integrand is equivalent to $|z^{-1-\alpha}|$ and one has $-1 -\alpha < -3$. It converges near $0$ because $-\alpha > -3$. The integral doesn't depend on $\omega$ by rotation invariance.

Comment: Thank you! That is the answer I need!